# Offset an index with the value in another register ARMv8

Tags: assembly, arm, addressing-mode, armv8

If I am able to load a register (R5) with a value from memory + some offset using the command:

```
LDR R5, [R12, #4]
```

How would I go about using the value of another register (R7 =0x0004 for example) as the offset?

```
LDR R5, [R12, &R7]
```

Comment: `LDR R5, [R12, R7]`?

Comment: or `LDR R5, [R12, R7]!` to write the updated offset back to `r12`.

Comment: Did ARMv8 introduce any new addressing modes for 32-bit ARM mode?  It introduced 64-bit AArch64 mode, but you're not using that.  Mostly just surprised to see question about 32-bit ARM stuff tagged with only ARMv8, especially features that have existed forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost have it, but the `&` symbol doesn't belong.  It's simply

```
LDR R5, [R12, R7]
```

Answer (score 0):

Question was answered in the original questions comment section. Will mark as answered when StackOverflow allows me in two days.

Comment: In future if a comment provides the answer or hint you were looking for, you can copy that into an answer of your own.  (Make it community wiki if you don't want to take credit for other people's work).  But *don't* just post "it was answered in comments" *as* an answer.  Always make sure anything you post as an answer does contain, within this post, an answer to the question.  So if comments get cleaned up, the answer isn't gone.